# Global vars with jsFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

In the jsFiddle environment, I wish to create a loop that displays numbers 1 thru 10 in random order, with no repeats.

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mCFGf/)

Among other things, having difficulty with global variables in the jsFiddle environment.

Would appreciate:

1. Explanation re global vars in jsFiddle
2. Making my code work (desired goal: print numbers 1 to 10 in random order, via loop)

Thank you

For posterity, here is the code from the jsFiddle:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="response"></div>
<input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Get Next" />
```

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
var cnt;
var window.arrDone = [];

function nextQues() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*3) + 2;
}

$('#mybutt').click(function() {
    cnt++;
    console.log('Count is now: ' + cnt);
    if (cnt < 10) {
        nn = nextQues();
        console.log('Testing: ' + nn);
        if (window.arrDone.indexOf(nn) > -1) {
            console.log('Already Seen: ' + nn);
        }else{
            console.log('FOUND NEW: ' + nn);
            window.arrDone.push(nn);
        }
        $('#mybutt').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

---

**For Posterity:**

Anyone stumbling across this question while researching their own solution should also check out this, related, SO post:

[Is javascript namespace polluted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855434/is-javascript-namespace-polluted)

- Ensure you read the answer by Joe Enos, and comment discussion underneath

Comment: `var window.arrDone` is invalid syntax. That's your problem.

Comment: Is cnt not initialized anywhere on purpose or is that your question?

Comment: Globals in jsFiddle are no different from globals elsewhere, except that the contents of the script pane are wrapped in a function by default.

Comment: Take a look here https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/tips-and-tricks#console-iframe and select the result iframe context. There you will find your globals.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto that just helped me out a ton, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var cnt = 0;
var window = {};
window.arrDone = [];
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/msKYV/)**

Globals in jsfiddle are the same as in websites. Although the best is to use `no wrap` in jsfiddle's top-left menu, and have your own `.ready()` function. Otherwise it will wrap your code in a `onload` function that you don't have on your site.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, great explanation. Appreciate the revised fiddle. Thanks for all. +1 and accept.

Comment: I think it's important to mention that in the jsFiddle example, `cnt`, `window`, and `window.arrDone` are not global vars.