# Is javascript namespace polluted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I do not have a good grasp of the js namespace and am WAGing* re the title, but that's one of my guesses about what's happening.

- WAG = Wild Guess

My app is crashing (dramatically); trying to figure out why.  In fact, after 3 Q/A pairs, it blows up the entire Chrome tab..! *I'm beginning to suspect I've done something wrong in my code...*

**Warning: Save your browsing session before running these jsFiddles. (In Chrome, the jsFiddle only blows up its own tab but I can't comment on other browsers)**

[jsFiddle One](http://jsfiddle.net/zc6gE/)
[jsFiddle Two - dupe in case jsFiddle One blown away](http://jsfiddle.net/dRtFJ/)

Please help me to understand exactly which spectacular moronism I've committed today.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="result">
    <div class="truth tr0"><h2>---</h2></div>
    <div class="truth tr1"><h2>answer to one</h2></div>
    <div class="truth tr2"><h2>answer to two</h2></div>
    <div class="truth tr3"><h2>answer to three</h2></div>
    <div class="truth tr4"><h2>answer to four</h2></div>
 </div>   
<div id="replaceLink">
    <div class="youcould yc1">
        <a href="#2"><h2>QUESTION ONE</h2></a>
    </div>
    <div class="youcould yc2">
        <a href="#3"><h2>QUESTION TWO</h2></a>
    </div>
    <div class="youcould yc3">
        <a href="#4"><h2>QUESTION THREE</h2></a>
    </div>
    <div class="youcould yc4">
        <a href="#5"><h2>QUESTION FOUR</h2></a>
    </div>
    <div class="youcould yc5">
        <a href="#6"><h2>THANK YOU</h2></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="response"></div>
<input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Start Test" />
```

**Javascript/jQuery:**

```
var cnt = 0;
var window = {};
window.arrDone = [];

function nextQues() {
    if (window.arrDone.length == 4) return 5;

    success = 0;
    while (success == 0) {
        nn = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
        if (window.arrDone.indexOf(nn) == -1 && nn != 5) {
            success++;
            window.arrDone.push(nn);
        }
    }
    return nn;
}

$('.youcould, .truth').hide();
$('.tr0').show();

$('.youcould').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    thisA = window.arrDone[window.arrDone.length -1];
    $('.tr'+thisA).show();
});

$('.truth').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    nextQ = nextQues();
    $('.yc'+nextQ).show();
});

$('#mybutt').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.tr0').hide();
    nextQ = nextQues();
    $('.yc'+nextQ).show();
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing that `window.arrDone` is first empty, then `window.arrDone.indexOf(nn)` never even exists and `Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1` never produces 5, so you never get out of the `while` loop...

Comment: Your `while loop` runs infinitely on the third pass because it doesn't meet the condition.

Comment: `success` will never equal 0 after the first pass, therefore the while loop will never end. you can replicate this behavior with `while (true){}`

Comment: @Andy You were right - the random generator was the problem. Please post your answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your while loop runs infinitely on the third pass because it doesn't meet the condition.

Comment: Although Bergi's answer is more detailed (+1 to him for that), you were the first to show me the error of my ways. Couldn't *believe* it was that simple, but I did suggest that it was today's moronism. Thanks again Andy.

Answer (score 5):

My guess would be

```
var window = {};
```

`window` is special, so creating a global variable named `window` is begging for trouble.

Comment: indeed, its a reserved namespace, you can't just go round updated these things. Pure MADNESS!

Comment: In these instances I think the machine should display a message `Go for a walk`, immediately shut down and be unbootable for an hour.

Comment: Turns out this wasn't the problem, but I certainly appreciate the feedback. Still working on figuring out namespaces, as you see. +1 for the advice.

Comment: @gibberish Anytime - glad you got it worked out. You can check out [a list of reserved words, predefined classes, and global properties](http://javascript.about.com/library/blreserved.htm) - there are several there which could potentially conflict with what would otherwise be good variable names: `document`, `window`, `package`, `frame`, `images`, `screen`, etc., so it might be worth keeping this list handy if you are using a variable which looks like it might possibly mean something else.

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't erroneously choose that var name; I did so intentionally in an effort to create a global var in a jsFiddle. Several online posts/articles suggested that when create a global var, it is added to the window namespace (i.e.  myglobalvar == window.myglobalvar). However, it turned out that all I had to do was: (1) start jsFiddle with, under Framworks & Extensions, `No wrap in <head>` instead of `onLoad()`; (2) Add my own `$(document).ready()` wrapper, and (3) create var outside of document.ready. Who'd a thunk?

Answer (score 2):

At some point, `arrDone` will contain the numbers `1`, `2`, and `3`, as produced by your random generator (which will never produce `5`, btw). In that case, `nextQues()` does not abort and return five (as `arrDone.lenght == 3`), and will enter the loop. Your random generator produces nothing but the numbers `1`, `2`, and `3`, which always are already in the array, so the if-condition (that would end the loop) is *never* fulfilled. You have an infinite loop generating random numbers.

I guess you want

```
function nextQues() {
    var l = 4;
    if (window.arrDone.length >= l)
        return l+1;

    while (true) {
        var nn = Math.floor(Math.random() * l) + 1; // generate 1, 2, 3 or 4
        if (window.arrDone.indexOf(nn) == -1) {
            window.arrDone.push(nn);
            return nn;
        }
    }
}
```