# Jquery order of events

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net-core

have a button click in a form and have required validation when clicking on that button. I put in

if (!formHandle.valid()) { return; }

in the global site.js file where I want that event to fire first before the event for the actual button. Currently the jquery for the actual button fires first before the global jquery. How can I make sure that the global jquery fires first or is this even possible?

html

```
    <p id="vote-status" class="card-text forum-blue">

        @{if (@Model.VoteId != 0)
            {
                <text>
                    <br /Text.
                    <br />Text
                </text>
            }
            else
            {
                <text><br />Text.</text>
            }
        }
    </p>
    @{
        if (Model.AvailableVotingOptions != null)
        {
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.VotingOptionId,            
                                 Model.AvailableVotingOptions,                    
                "- Please select -",                   
                new { @class = "form-control", @id = "voting-options" })
        }
    }
   
<div class="card-footer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <button type="button"
                    class="btn btn-success btn-sm col-sm-12"
                    id="button"
                    data-action="submit">
                <i class="fas fa-vote-yea fa-fw"></i>
                @if (@Model.VoteId != 0)
                {
                    <text>Re-Cast Vote</text>
                }
                else
                {
                    <text>Vote</text>
                }

            </button>
        </div>           
    </div>
</div>
```

Site.js (event I want to hit first)

```
$(document).on("click",
'[data-action="submit"]',
function (e) {
    var formHandle = $(this).closest('form');
    if (!formHandle.valid()) {
        return;
    }
    if (formHandle.valid()) {
        blockUI();
    }
});
```

Document.js

```
$(document).on("click",
    '#button',
    function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var post_url = $("#form-vote").attr("action"); //get form action url
        var request_method = $("#form-vote").attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
        var form_data = $("#form-vote");
        $.ajax({
            url: post_url,
            type: request_method,
            data: form_data.serialize(),
            processData: false,
            async: true
        }).done(function (objOperations) {
            if ($("#validation-error")[0].textContent.trim() === "") {
                ShowVoteStatus(true, "Your document is submitted successfully.");
               
           
        }).fail(function (error) {
            ShowVoteStatus(false,
                "Your document was not submitted successfully.");
        }).always(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            $.unblockUI();
        });;
    });
```

https://codepen.io/bootsy1974/pen/ExggoQg

Comment: you could defer execution of the button handler with setTimeout() for example

Comment: well since you are using jquery [deferred-object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) might be a better option

Comment: Please make your code runnable in a snippet on SO and/or change this fiddle to mostly your code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835396/global-vars-with-jsfiddle

Comment: Which deferred-object would I use? And where would it go in the global js or document js?

Comment: The proper way to deal with this sort of thing is using a capturing event, in [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). But you'd have to use `addEventListener` to create the event: jQuery `on` can't do capturing events.

Comment: Why call `formHandle.valid()` twice?  The only way it can get to the second case is if you've already verified that it is valid.  Otherwise the return would have happened.

Comment: `<br /Text.` ...

Comment: <br /Text?? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

why do different functions? you can make a check before sending in the second function.
if its possible and this same one button
if its not possible to try after validation use

`$("#button").trigger("click");`

```
$(document).on("click",
'[data-action="submit"]',
function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    var formHandle = $(this).closest('form');
    if (!formHandle.valid()) {
        return;
    }
    if (formHandle.valid()) {
        blockUI();
     $("#button").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

but `formHandle.valid` is not a function
need changed '#button' from button and created another element to binding this function. in another to try sending without validation. need do dependeces sending from validating. but you have to parallel working.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
<div id="button"></div>  
            <button type="button"
                    class="btn btn-success btn-sm col-sm-12"
                    
                    data-action="submit">
                <i class="fas fa-vote-yea fa-fw"></i>
                @if (@Model.VoteId != 0)
                {
                    <text>Re-Cast Vote</text>
                }
                else
                {
                    <text>Vote</text>
                }

            </button>
        </div>
```

and this have not '}'

```
$(document).on("click",
    '#button',
    function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var post_url = $("#form-vote").attr("action"); //get form action url
        var request_method = $("#form-vote").attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
        var form_data = $("#form-vote");
        $.ajax({
            url: post_url,
            type: request_method,
            data: form_data.serialize(),
            processData: false,
            async: true
        }).done(function (objOperations) {
            if ($("#validation-error")[0].textContent.trim() === "") {
                ShowVoteStatus(true, "Your document is submitted successfully.");
               
           
        }}).fail(function (error) {
            ShowVoteStatus(false,
                "Your document was not submitted successfully.");
        }).always(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            $.unblockUI();
        });;
    });
```

https://codepen.io/romanown/pen/QWKKERZ
deleted not worked validating
https://codepen.io/romanown/pen/zYKKKqv

Comment: Not sure if this will work. I want to be able to use the global.js file for validation first because that is used in a lot of forms where the document.js #button is used in just one form.

Comment: i added example for this way. but better changed '#button'. show html plase

Comment: Are you asking to see my html code? Also I tried you modified code and it didn't work.

Comment: I updated my original post with html. You can see the form with the button in it.

Comment: thank you. i can not see '#button'. but i see id="vote-button". need to change in js '#button' to "#vote-button"

Comment: It is vote-button I changed it to button for posting here so that doesn't matter. It's still not working using your code.

Comment: What did you change? I see the id="button" is gone, is that what you changed?

Comment: removed '#button' from button to prevent parallel work. and whot it formHandle.valid()? and not see 'form'. and different "#form-vote"

Comment: second function not have ''}'. i added it in the answere

Comment: can you helped the codepen? and added '}'?

Comment: This is closer. It does validate when nothing is selected but now when I do select something it just hangs without submitting the form.

Comment: to add https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js to settings to working it. but whot it formHandle.valid()?